# left bounded chain complex $Z$ such that $Z \otimes_R^{\mathbf L} (R_P/PR_P)$ is uniformly right bounded as $P$ varies over prime ideals of $R$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, local-rings, derived-categories

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Let $Z$ be a left bounded chain complex of finitely generated $R$-modules. If there exists an integer $n$ such that for every prime ideal $P$ of $R$, the derived tensor-product $Z \otimes_R^{\mathbf L} (R_P/PR_P)$ is homologically right bounded upto $n$, then is $Z$ itself homologically bounded?

I feel like this must be some sort of Nakayama kind of argument, but I am not sure.

Please help.

Comment: Is the differential left to right, or right to left?

Comment: Assume that $Z$ is quasi-isomorphic to a complex $C$ of finite free $R$-modules such that $C/mC$ is exact (ie let’s replace, for the sake of simplicity, “homologically bounded” by “homologically trivial”). By induction, you can show that for any $R$-module of finite length $M$, $C \otimes M$ is exact; in particular $C/m^nC$ is exact for all $n$. By Artin-Rees (I think) this means that $C \otimes \hat{R}$ is exact and thus that $C$ is exact.